# $\forall \alpha$ ordinal, Prove that $\alpha+1=S(\alpha)$

Tags: proof-writing, set-theory, ordinals, transfinite-induction

$\forall \alpha$ ordinals, Prove that $\alpha+1=S(\alpha)$

My question is would this require transfinite induction to prove? and if so how would one do the successor case?

Comment: No (explicit) induction needed. Just the definitions of $+$ and $S$.

Comment: How do you define $\alpha+1$ and how do you define $S(\alpha)$?

Comment: $S(\alpha)=\alpha\cup\{x\}$  and for the addition are you referring to ordinal addition ?